# Algebraic field extension and intermediate integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, integral-domain

> Let $F/K$ be an algebraic field extension. Suppose $D$ is an integral domain with $K\subset D\subset F$. Show that $D$ is a field.

\\\\\My idea was wrong, so I have to delete them.
\\\\\\

Thanks!

Comment: An algebraic field extension is not necessarily of finite degree; you cannot conclude that $\dim_KF=d$. It is also not necessary that $a^p\in D$ for any $p>0$.

Comment: $D = K[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$ where the $a_i$ are algebraic, and $  K[a_1,\ldots,a_n]= K(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ by the fundamental theorem $K[x]/(f(x)) \cong K[a]$  where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$.

Comment: Sorry I mistake algebraic extension with simple extension...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $a\in D\setminus\{0\}$ then $D$ contains the $K$-algebra $K[a]$, and because $a$ is algebraic over $K$ we have $K[a]=K(a)$, therefore $a$ has an inverse in $D$.

Comment: It reduces to show that any $a \in F$ is algebraic over $K$

Comment: Exactly! The use of K[a] = K(a) is genius!

Comment: @Ivan : How would you show $a$ is algebraic ?

Comment: @user1952009 a field extension L/K is called algebraic if every element of L is algebraic over K.

Comment: @Ivan If you want, but we only know $L/K$ is a finite extension : of the form $K(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ where $c_i$ are algebraic over $K$

Comment: @user1952009 You are exactly right, and that tells $a$ is algebraic, so this answer has no errors right?

Comment: @Ivan : I meant you need to show that the sum, product and quotient of algebraic numbers is algebraic, using the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Number_theory) or the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)

Comment: Oh I get it. You are right. I overlooked this step.